# Creating .dylib dynamic library from source files in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, c, static-libraries, dylib

I have downloaded the qrencode source files from this http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html

Can any one list out the steps to follow for creating the dylib files ?

Thanks

Comment: At the very least, you need to install `pkg-config`. If you’re not comfortable with building software on Mac OS that doesn’t readily on Mac OS, consider using a package management software such as MacPorts or Fink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Apple's developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002073-SW1)

or just follow the instructions from the page you quote

> ./configure
>   make
>   make install